# On click function to generated elements

Tags: c#, wpf, events, user-interface

I have a grid that is being populated through code. This is my implementation:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
     {
          Image oImage = new Image();
          Window.myGrid.Children.Add(oImage);

          oImageSource.UriSource = oImageUri;

          oImage.Source = oImageSource;

          Grid.SetRow(oImage, i);
          Grid.SetColumn(oImage, j);
     }
}
```

I'm looking for a solution that with it I will be able to do the next:

When someone clicks on the object `oImage`, which I added as a child, a function will trigger, and the slot's **row** and **column** will be it's parameters.

So if I have the next grid (each number represents an object that was appended to the grid):

### 1 | 2 | 3

### 4 | 5 | 6

### 7 | 8 | 9

Clicking on `9` will trigger the function `func(2, 2)` (row's and column's index is 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the *closure* feature of lambda expressions to make this work, though you have to be careful.

Inside your inner `for` loop, you do something like this:

```
Image oImage = new Image();
Window.myGrid.Children.Add(oImage);

var row = i;
var col = j;
oImage.MouseUp += (sender, args) => func(row, col);
```

This will attach the specified lambda expression to the `MouseUp` event for the `Image` instance, which will call your function with the appropriate values. The lambda expression will close over those variables, even after they leave scope, and it will remember their values.

The key here is that you need to use *locally scoped variables* as the parameters. By doing so, you will create a new copy of `row` and `col` each pass through the loop. More specifically, you can ***not*** use `func(i,j)` -- the lamba will "remember" the last value that `i` and `j` had, and will always called `func(3,3)` on all 9 images.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the image to an handler like

```
oImage.MouseUp +=new MouseButtonEventHandler(oImage_MouseUp);
```

Then in the handler you can use Grid.GetColumn and Grid.GetRow to get the properties

```
private void oImage_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image bb = (Image)sender;
        func(Grid.GetRow(bb), Grid.GetColumn(bb));
    }
```